# wget on Windows - same file keeps getting overwritten

Tags: wget

I'm using wget on Windows 7. I'm downloading a lot of files such as this:

http://stats.grok.se/json/en/200712/Wikipedia:WikiProject%20Video%20games

except that I am changing the date each time. The URLs are all listed in a text file I am using as input for wget using the -i option.

```
wget -i "C:\New folder (2)\input.txt" -P "C:\New folder (2)"
```

My problem is that wget keeps overwriting the same file over and over again instead of creating new files. Is there a way to force wget to append some unique string to the end so each file is saved? I heard this was the default behavior but wget is not doing it.

GNU Wget 1.11.4

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the `wget` command you are actually using ...

Comment: Okay I added the command line.